# QML module not found in ROS project

Tags: qt, import, qml, ros

I have an example ROS project with 1 package `dashboard`. The `CMakeLists.txt` of this package is here:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(dashboard VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on )

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH $ENV{CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Quick QuickControls2 Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Core Quick QuickControls2 Widgets REQUIRED)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        src/main.cpp
)

set(PROJECT_RESOURCES
    qml.qrc
    imports.qrc
)

list(APPEND QML_IMPORT "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/")
list(APPEND QML_IMPORT "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/imports")
list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES QML_IMPORT)
set(QML2_IMPORT_PATH "${QML_IMPORT}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
set(QML_IMPORT_PATH "${QML_IMPORT}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)


if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )
else()
    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
      ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
      ${QT_RESOURCES_CPP}
      ${${PROJECT_NAME}_MOCS}
      ${${PROJECT_NAME}_QML}
      ${PROJECT_RESOURCES}
    )
endif()

target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC SOURCE_DIR="${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
    Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core
    Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Quick
    Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::QuickControls2
    Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets
    )

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_import_qml_plugins(${PROJECT_NAME})
    qt_finalize_executable(${PROJECT_NAME})
endif()
```

I have set both `QML_IMPORT_PATH` and `QML_IMPORT_PATH`, but still have an issue `QML module not found (Themes.MyTheme).`
Here is `MyTheme` `qmldir`:

```
module Themes.MyTheme
singleton Theme 1.0 Theme.qml
```

The project is compiled and launched, but autocomplete don't working and `Theme` isn't defined.
The question is: how to correctly import module in .qml file in ROS project for everything working?

Comment: maybe a stupid question but is Qt6 installed in this system? I also would create a simple QML/CMake project using QtCreator and copy the cmake setting from that

Comment: @folibis, I'm using Qt 5.15.2

Comment: [This topic](https://forum.qt.io/topic/136431/qml-module-not-found-in-ros-project) is duplicated on Qt Forum.
Still waiting for the responce, thanks